# How to properly loop two functions to each other

Tags: javascript, html, infinite-loop

```js
var Arr = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

function Switch(a) {
  document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML = a.join('');
  Try();
}

function Try() {
  for (i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
    var Ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    switch (Ran) {
      case 0:
        Arr[i] = "|";
        break;
      case 1:
        Arr[i] = "1";
        break;
    }
  }

  Switch(Arr);
}

Try();
```

```html
<div class="bdy">
  <p id="dem">AHAHHAHAHH!!!</p>
</div>
```

I need the javascript to continuously change the contents of the paragraph, but it only changes whenever the page load. I think it's because I'm calling the function after the page has loaded or the Switch function still doesn't recognize the Try function because it was defined after it.
I don't really know how to solve this problem, please help. Thanks

Comment: do you want reapeat function continusly?

Comment: You must be getting error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" as you are using indirect recursion.

Comment: This code loops forever. it will stuck the CPU.
You can use setInterval() instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
var el = document.getElementById("dem");
function updateData(a) {
    el.innerHTML = a.join('');
}

function changeData() {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) ? "|" : "1";
    }
    updateData(arr);
}
setInterval(changeData, 500);
```

```html
<div class="bdy" >
    <p id="dem">AHAHHAHAHH!!!</p>
</div>
```

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to call a function at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

Some annotations:

- Use function and variales with starting lower case letters, because starting eith upper case letter denoted instanciable function an all caps means constants as convention.
- Use the functions name directly for `setInterval`.
- If you need only one letter to replace, then you could use a string with the letters and an index for getting the letter.

```js
function updateElement(a) {
    document.getElementById("dem").innerHTML = a.join('');
}

function change() {
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = "|1"[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)];
    }
    updateElement(array);
}

var array = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];

setInterval(change, 500);
```

```html
<p id="dem">AHAHHAHAHH!!!</p>
```